# How to run elasticsearch python unit tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, elasticsearch, testing

I am trying to run ElasticSearch python tests from official elasticsearch-py realease here : https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/tree/5.x

Actually, I have done all the steps mentionned into elasticsearch-py/test_elasticsearch/README.rst and it turns out that I can run Elasticsearch in a Container with success.

But so far running the tests is failing everytime.
I have got 12 errors out of 124 runned tests and it looks like `test_elasticsearch.test_connection.TestRequestsConnection` is always failing due to :

> AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute
>   'merge_environment_settings'.

What I have done so far is downloading the official Repo, `export ES_VERSION=5.4` and then running ElasticSearch with `./start_elasticsearch.sh`. After that I am able to navigate to localhost:9200 into my Web Browser.

Then I've changed `TEST_ES_SERVER` into 'localhost:9200' into *elasticsearch5/helpers/test.py* file.

I am running the tests using `python setup.py test` or `python run_tests.py` but here's what the console returns in both case :

> No elasticsearch repo found...
>
> ........................./home/user/bin/git/elasticsearch-py/elasticsearch5/client/utils.py:47:
>   UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both
>   arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal quote_plus(_escape(p), b',*') for p in parts if p not in SKIP_IN_PATH)
>
> .EE.EEE.E..EE.EE.EE................................................................................
>
> ERROR: test_body_attached (test_elasticsearch.test_connection.TestRequestsConnection)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last) :
>
> File
>   "/home/user/bin/git/elasticsearch-py/test_elasticsearch/test_connection.py",
>   line 213, in test_body_attached
>
> request = self._get_request(con, 'GET', '/', body='{"answer": 42}')
>
> File "/home/user/bin/git/elasticsearch-py/test_elasticsearch/test_connection.py", line 75, in _get_request status, headers, data =
>   connection.perform_request(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/user/bin/git/elasticsearch-py/elasticsearch5/connection/http_requests.py",
>   line 72, in perform_request
>
> settings =
>   self.session.merge_environment_settings(prepared_request.url, {},
>   None, None, None)
>
> AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute
>   merge_environment_settings'

Do you have any idea how I can make this work ? Locally at first.

Thanks and regards.